# Dynamics 365 Business Central - Merge multiple report layouts into one email

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, rdlc, erp, dynamics-business-central

In the report selection modal (Report Selection - Sales) you are able to select multiple layouts that will be rendered when a sales invoice is posted. Obviously you would want the layouts like the Swiss QR Bill to appear in the same email sent to the user as the invoice itself, but when selecting a second report layout, two emails are generated and sent to the user.

[image: Report Layout Selection]

As you see, the currently selected report has a layout description for the email generation. How does one attach both PDF's generated by the report selection into a single email? Is this possible without custom code based on the functionality of the system or does one need to extend the base application code?